# How to use a FORTRAN90 subroutines with Mathematica 8.0?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fortran90

I am working on a project and I would like to use a FORTRAN90 subroutine which give me some outputs. I want to use these outputs to use them with sliders and graphs. That is why the inputs would come from the Mathematica interface, then go to the FORTRAN90 subroutine and finally the outputs would come back in Mathematica for visualization.

I read about Mathlink but I do not know how to use it for this application.

Someone has already answered for a similar question on stackoverflow, but it was only for a "one way".

Comment: This [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5675/52) of on [Mathematica.se] covers what is needed for a specific application, but it can be generalized.

Comment: Also maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!starred/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/yxS7kD6CmRI) will be of help